Nonconformant arguments in Octave
So I got this exercise:
Using formula (18), implement the Gauss-Legendre method. The attached function [t, w] = gauleg(n) returns the node values ti and weights wi for the given polynomial degree n.
Formula 18
This is my code:
% Function to generate nodes and weights for Gauss-Legendre quadrature
function [t, w] = gauleg(n)
  % Create a matrix related to Legendre polynomials
  beta = 0.5 ./ sqrt(1 - (2 * (1:n-1)).^(-2));  % Calculate parameters
  T = diag(beta, 1) + diag(beta, -1);  % Tridiagonal matrix

  % Compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors
  [V, D] = eig(T);  % Eigenvalue decomposition

  % Nodes are the eigenvalues
  t = diag(D);  % Nodes
  [t, idx] = sort(t);  % Sort nodes

  % Weights are the square of the first element of each eigenvector, multiplied by 2
  w = 2 * (V(1, idx)).^2;  % Compute weights based on sorting index
end


% Function to compute integrals using Gauss-Legendre quadrature
function I = f_gaussLegendre(f, a, b, n)
  % Get the nodes and weights
  [t, w] = gauleg(n);
  
  % Midpoint and half of the interval's length
  c = (a + b) / 2;  % Midpoint of the interval
  d = (b - a) / 2;  % Half of the interval's length
  
  % Compute function values at the correct points
  F = arrayfun(@(ti) f(c + d * ti), t);  % Compute function values at the nodes
  weighted_sum = sum(w .* F);  % Sum the weighted function values
  
  % Compute the final integral result
  I = d * weighted_sum;  % Final integration result
end

% Test code
% Integration interval
a = 0;
b = 2;

% Function to integrate
f = @(x) x.^3 + 2*x.^2 + 1;

% Compute integral using Gauss-Legendre method
n_values = [2, 4, 6];  % Example values for n
results = zeros(size(n_values));  % Allocate space for results

% Loop through different values of n
for i = 1:length(n_values)
    results(i) = f_gaussLegendre(f, a, b, n_values(i));
end

% Display the results
disp("Results from Gauss-Legendre method:");
disp("n  | result");
disp([n_values; results]');  % Display the values for n and their corresponding results


and the otuput of this code is
error: =: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x1, op2 is 1x2)
Results from Gauss-Legendre method:
n  | result
   2   0
   4   0
   6   0

"I don't know where the error is or how to fix it, because Jupyter Notebook doesn't show which line has the error.

It is always a good idea to inspect first a single computation instead of going for the whole thing by a loop immediately. Running
f_gaussLegendre(f, a, b, n_values(1))

reveals that your function returns a vector [11.333 11.333] which does not fit into the scalar variable result(1), hence Octave reports the above error.
I am not sure whether the %debug magic command works in Jupyter for Octave, but if not, you can always revert to the good trustable ancient way and just print out values to debug. Printing out the sizes of the w, F, and weighed_sum variables by
...
weighted_sum = sum(w .* F);  % Sum the weighted function values
disp(size(w)); disp(size(F)); disp(size(weighted_sum));
...

reveals that the sizes are [1 2], [2 1], and [1 2], respectively. So clearly there is the problem as the multiplication w .* F results in a 2x2 matrix and sum will simply sum up its columns. Perhaps you wanted to do there simply w*F, or maybe a transpose is missing somewhere.

The magic commands are specific to each kernel. I have no idea what magics are implemented by the Octave kernel. But the logic way to debug Octave code is to just boot up Octave. It has a built-in debugger and also gives much better error messages than the Jupyter Octave kernel.
